# Partially bold string in android

Tags: android

I want to bold the first word of each line. But rather then being bold it shows entire code!

```
 private void addAsimA(ArrayList<String> products) {
         products.add("<b>Apple</b> It is red");
         products.add("<b>Banana</b> It is yellow");
         products.add("<b>Mango</b> It is green");
```

How can I get output like this:

**Apple** It is red

**Banana** It is yellow

**Mango** It is green

Here is the full java file

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView txtv, txt1;
    ImageView imgv;


       // List view
    private ListView lv;

    // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    // ArrayList for Listview
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

     ArrayList<String> products = new ArrayList<String>();


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         addAsimA(products);
         addAsimB(products);
    }



 private void addAsimA(ArrayList<String> products) {        

             products.add("<b>Apple</b> It is red");
             products.add("<b>Banana</b> It is yellow");
             products.add("<b>Mango</b> It is green");
              }

             private void addAsimB(ArrayList<String> products) {

                 products.add("<b>Flower</b> It is nice");
                 products.add("<b>Fog</b> It is white");
                 products.add("<b>Rose</b> It is pink");

                  lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);


                  // your code is added here but what is the problem?
                    TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_list);
                    txt1.setText(Html.fromHtml(products.get(productList)));


                    // Adding items to listview
                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_list,   products);
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);                

         }
    }
```

XML file for text view is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Product Name -->

     <com.examdple.customproduct.CustomTextView

            android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="4sp"
            android:id="@+id/product_list"
            android:paddingLeft="20sp"
            android:paddingBottom="2sp"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If anybody want the file: http://www.mediafire.com/?op37c1itodd8724

Answer (score 8):

Like this:

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTxtV);
txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(products.get(index)));
```

Comment: I cannot understand where to put it? what does index means? Can you elaborate please?

Comment: index = the index of the string you want to get from your ArrayList; I edited my answer. It should be clear now.

Comment: I am not going to download your project, if you want help then post the relevant code.

Comment: Now you don't need to download the code; Just see above. I have updated the code. Please have a look.

Comment: I am still waiting for you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put your string in strings.xml and change it like this,

```
<string name="hello"><b>Hello</b> World, fh!</string>
```

and set this text like this

```
android:text="@string/hello"
```

Comment: that's not working without .setText(Html.fromHtml(yourStringIdHere))
#smallPrecision