# Are there any views to help me to show HTML text?

Tags: android

I have some text with html tags: a, br, b, and I need to show this text for user. Are there any views or ways to show this text for user keeping formatting? Thank you in advance

UPDATED:

There is the code:

```
    TextView view=new TextView(this);
    view.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href='www.google.com'>link</a>"));
    view.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL);
```

When I click by link there are no actions. How can I fix it? I need to open a browser.

Comment: I just answered this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175481/partially-bold-string-in-android/14175517#14175517

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have used some HTML tags in your string resource then you can use..

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(R.string.your_string));
```

And set the tag **android:autoLink="all"** in your textview XML or

**view.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());** in java.

It will give you desired output...:)

Comment: It's good, but I can't click by link in TextView. How can I fix it?

Comment: Please use view.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()); instead of view.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL); and see my edited answer.