# Changing the color of the lines in list view itmes

Tags: android

In the normal list view the separator lines are deemed but when I switch to full screen mode it becomes too dark. How can I control the color of the lines?

For easier understanding, Please see the image here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15065300/layout.png

Code of activity XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ProductList" >

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView0"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#123456"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:drawablePadding="6sp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="8sp"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/> 


        <!-- List View -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Code for List_Item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Product Name -->

     <com.examdple.customproduct.CustomTextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#111111"
            android:paddingTop="10sp"
            android:id="@+id/product_list"
            android:paddingLeft="20sp"
            android:paddingBottom="5sp"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The entire project here http://www.mediafire.com/?umt91j6acq8b6gm

Answer (score 1):

You should use `android:divider` attribute:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:divider="#FFFF0000"
    android:dividerHeight="1dip"/>
```

Comment: I have another unsolved issue posted 10 hours ago. Could you please see this here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175481/partially-bold-string-in-android